# Google Play Games OAuth-2: app visibility on Google+

Tags: google-plus, google-oauth, google-play-games

I'm trying to resolve an issue regarding Google+ and authorizing users for an app using Google OAuth-2.  More specifically, I find the authorization is successful when the user presses Accept on the consent screen; using the oauth playground and the auth/games scope, that looks like: http://retrofist.com/temp/Auth_01.png

However, if I then check my app privileges at plus.google.com/apps, I see the playground listed as visible to 'Only You': http://retrofist.com/temp/Auth_02.png - even though 'Anyone on the web' was selected on the consent screen.  As I'm using Google Play Games for leaderboards, the result is that no one can see any leaderboard entries until they have manually corrected this to 'Public' visibility.

Can anyone explain a reason or workaround for this?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I observed similar issues, my scores was not published publicly to the leaderboard of the game. I then realized that, this is only for users whose email is defined as tester email. I could see the scores as publicly posted after deleting those emails from tester list.

Comment: This bug, incorrect documentation, other? affects me, no tester emails are in place. This impacts ALL users of my apps. Using the REST-API.